# Formatting UITextField as a time hh:mm

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I want a UITextField to correctly format an inputted number as a time, adding minutes using "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" to obtain this result every time a new number is pressed:

```
i.e.: 
00:00
00:08 = 8 pressed
01:23 = 8 -> 3 pressed
08:30 = 8 -> 3 -> 0 pressed
```

The UITextField is a subview into a Custom UITableViewCell.
I can't figure out, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Simple

in the H declare:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    int hh;
    int mm;
    int ss;
}


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *outputLabel;

@end
```

In the M

```
-(void)generateText
{
    NSString *hhString;
    NSString *mmString;
    NSString *ssString;

    if (hh < 10){
        hhString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",hh];
    } else {
        hhString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",hh];
    }
    //
    if (mm < 10){
        mmString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",mm];
    } else {
        mmString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",mm];
    }
    if (ss < 10){
        ssString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"0%d",ss];
    } else {
        ssString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",ss];
    }





    NSString *outputText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:%@:%@",hhString,mmString,ssString];
    NSLog(@"output string = %@",outputText);
    outputLabel.text = outputText;

}


-(IBAction)addHH:(id)sender
{
    hh = hh +1;
    [self generateText];
}

-(IBAction)addMM:(id)sender
{
    mm = mm +1;
    [self generateText];
}

-(IBAction)addSS:(id)sender
{
    ss = ss +1;
    [self generateText];
}
```

In Interface builder use 3 buttons to activate the appropriate IBActions

Comment: Thanks, but i use UIKeyboard with NumberKeypad and i want to add minutes while i type numbers.

Comment: so change the pad to generate the number opposing to +1 - that is to say that when u press 8 it will do hh = 8 in the IBAction

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Use this delegate method to change the text field accordingly

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // You should already have set some string in the text field
    if (/*user input is between 0-9*/) {
        NSString *text = /* Format your text */
        textFiled.text = text;
        // Return NO to disable editing done by the user
        // Not required to return here if you always return NO;
        return NO;
    }
    // Return NO if you do not want to let user make any changes, otherwise YES
    return YES;
}
```

I have tested it, but changing the `textField.text` inside this method may call this recursively and fail. If this is the case, use a flag to keep track of what changes are made by you and what by the user. Return `YES` if the flag is ON and `NO` otherwise.

Comment: I'm using this method and i want to obtain this result every time a new number is pressed: 00:00
00:08 = 8 pressed
01:23 = 8 -> 3 pressed
08:30 = 8 -> 3 -> 0 pressed